# Clang generates unusual code for pointer subtraction, is this a bug?

Tags: c++, clang, x86-64

Look at this simple code, it calculates the number array elements between `e` and `b`:

```
#include <cstddef>

struct Foo {
    char z[3];
};

std::ptrdiff_t size(const Foo *b, const Foo *e) {
    std::ptrdiff_t r = e - b;
    //if (r < 0) __builtin_unreachable();
    return r;
}
```

Clang generates fine code for this (using `-O2`):

```
size(Foo const*, Foo const*):                       # @size(Foo const*, Foo const*)
        sub     rsi, rdi
        movabs  rax, -6148914691236517205
        imul    rax, rsi
        ret
```

However, if I uncomment the commented line, I'd expect that it doesn't change the asm code. But it does, and clang generates a larger and supposedly less efficient code:

```
size(Foo const*, Foo const*):                       # @size(Foo const*, Foo const*)
        mov     rax, rsi
        sub     rax, rdi
        movabs  rcx, -6148914691236517205
        mul     rcx
        mov     rax, rdx
        shr     rax
        ret
```

Is this a bug?

Similar case, look at this code:

```
#include <cstddef>

struct Foo {
    char z[3];
};

void bar(std::ptrdiff_t);

void foo(const Foo *b, const Foo *e) {
    std::ptrdiff_t s = e - b;

    for (std::ptrdiff_t i=0; i<s; i++) {
        bar(i);
    }
}
```

The generated code is this:

```
foo(Foo const*, Foo const*):                        # @foo(Foo const*, Foo const*)
        push    r14
        push    rbx
        push    rax
        sub     rsi, rdi
        test    rsi, rsi
        jle     .LBB0_3
        movabs  rcx, -6148914691236517205
        mov     rax, rsi
        mul     rcx
        shr     rdx
        cmp     rdx, 2
        mov     r14d, 1
        cmovge  r14, rdx
        xor     ebx, ebx
.LBB0_2:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    bar(long)
        add     rbx, 1
        cmp     r14, rbx
        jne     .LBB0_2
.LBB0_3:
        add     rsp, 8
        pop     rbx
        pop     r14
        ret
```

Notice the same, less efficient number of elements calculation. I think this happens because clang first handles the case when `e` < `b`, so it knows that `s` is non-negative, so it applies the same "optimization" as the previous case.

And also, there is a comparison with `2`, and a `cmov`. Aren't these unnecessary? Is this some trick, or a bug?

godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/zMeY1MKh7

Comment: If `Foo` points to different instances, then the code exhibits undefined behavior.  You cannot use `ptrdiff_t` on items that are not in the same array.  [Documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/ptrdiff_t).

Comment: https://repnz.github.io/posts/reversing-optimizations-division/

Comment: Is there an CPU architecture, where `mul` is faster than `imul`?

Comment: @Sebastian: the two operand `imul` only calculates 64-bit result, while the one operand `mul` calculates a 128-bit one. So it would make sense that, if anything, that the 2-op `imul` should be faster (or at least, not slower) than the 1-op `mul`. I checked some latest CPUs in Agner Fog's table, and these run at the same speed.

Comment: With clang `-emit-llvm` can be used to get an architecture independent intermediate representation format output. It gives `%6 = sdiv exact i64 %5, 3, !dbg !36` for the first example without the commented line, and `%6 = udiv exact i64 %5, 3, !dbg !36` with it. And `%8 = udiv exact i64 %5, 3, !dbg !48` for the second example.

Comment: @Sebastian: Thanks! Supposedly clang has a special exact division handling for sdiv, but not for udiv.

Comment: `-mllvm -print-after-all` is even cooler :-)

Comment: @Sebastian: No, `imul r64,r64` is always at least as fast as `mul r64`.  Usually faster, like single uop vs. 2 from having to write the high half.  (Interestingly, `mul r32` is 3 uops on modern Intel vs. 2 for `mul r64`; perhaps the multiplier HW naturally produces a 128-bit output split into low/high half so it just needs an extra uop to write the high half, but extra splitting work is needed to split a 64-bit output into 32-bit halves.)

Answer (score 4):

I would say the problem lies here (line 2942 of https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/lib/Target/X86/X86FastISel.cpp)

```
// FastISel doesn't have a pattern for all X86::MUL*r and X86::IMUL*r. Emit
// it manually.
if (BaseOpc == X86ISD::UMUL && !ResultReg) {
  static const uint16_t MULOpc[] =
    { X86::MUL8r, X86::MUL16r, X86::MUL32r, X86::MUL64r };
  static const MCPhysReg Reg[] = { X86::AL, X86::AX, X86::EAX, X86::RAX };
  // First copy the first operand into RAX, which is an implicit input to
  // the X86::MUL*r instruction.
  BuildMI(*FuncInfo.MBB, FuncInfo.InsertPt, DbgLoc,
          TII.get(TargetOpcode::COPY), Reg[VT.SimpleTy-MVT::i8])
    .addReg(LHSReg);
  ResultReg = fastEmitInst_r(MULOpc[VT.SimpleTy-MVT::i8],
                             TLI.getRegClassFor(VT), RHSReg);
} else if (BaseOpc == X86ISD::SMUL && !ResultReg) {
  static const uint16_t MULOpc[] =
    { X86::IMUL8r, X86::IMUL16rr, X86::IMUL32rr, X86::IMUL64rr };
  if (VT == MVT::i8) {
    // Copy the first operand into AL, which is an implicit input to the
    // X86::IMUL8r instruction.
    BuildMI(*FuncInfo.MBB, FuncInfo.InsertPt, DbgLoc,
           TII.get(TargetOpcode::COPY), X86::AL)
      .addReg(LHSReg);
    ResultReg = fastEmitInst_r(MULOpc[0], TLI.getRegClassFor(VT), RHSReg);
  } else
    ResultReg = fastEmitInst_rr(MULOpc[VT.SimpleTy-MVT::i8],
                                TLI.getRegClassFor(VT), LHSReg, RHSReg);
}
```

The first if block is about unsigned multiplication (`X86ISD::UMUL`), the second else if block is about signed multiplication (`X86ISD::SMUL`).

For unsigned multiplication first a copy to `RAX` (or its shorter variants) is emitted before the actual multiplication.

For signed multiplication with operand size > 1 byte, the small else block at the bottom is executed, which directly does signed multiplication.

With x86 there is a two-operand-form of `imul` (signed multiply) - https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/imul, but not of `mul` (unsigned multiply) - https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mul.

The optimizations for exchanging divisions with multiplications and detecting signed vs. unsigned are done in the architecture independent part of LLVM. (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/llvm/lib/CodeGen/SelectionDAG/TargetLowering.cpp (lines 5108, 5186, 5334).

The x86 backend does not check that it could use a signed multiply instruction for cases, where the unsigned operand is below (0x8000000000000000).

The additional shift right instruction is a separate issue from the register copying, which also happens one other architectures, which have an unsigned multiplication instruction as expressive as the signed one (e.g. ARM).

As suggested by you it is related to `BuildExactSDIV()` (in line 5108 of TargetLowering.cpp), which also contains:

```
  // Shift the value upfront if it is even, so the LSB is one.
  if (UseSRA) {
    // TODO: For UDIV use SRL instead of SRA.
    SDNodeFlags Flags;
    Flags.setExact(true);
    Res = DAG.getNode(ISD::SRA, dl, VT, Res, Shift, Flags);
    Created.push_back(Res.getNode());
  }
```

One should note the TODO comment about how this could be implemented for UDIV.

The unsigned division in `BuildUDIV()` (line 5334) has no similar option as `BuildSDIV` (line 5190) to call a `BuildExactSDIV()` (5219). There exists no `BuildExactUDIV()` and the normal buildup always involves a shift.

Comment: "The additional shift right instruction is a separate issue". I'm not sure about this. Note, that the first version uses the bottom 64-bit of the result, the second version uses the top 64-bit. In my opinion, this means that we have different algorithms here: the first one uses modular multiplicative inverse (only works for exact cases), the second one uses the non-modular inverse (always works). Based on your comments below the question, I think that the issue is that udiv doesn't have the modular multiplicative inverse special case. But I could be wrong.

Comment: I checked `TargetLowering.cpp`, and it has `BuildExactSDIV`, but has no `BuildExactUDIV`. And it seems that `BuildUDIV` doesn't check for exactness like `BuildSDIV` does. But llvm has a large codebase, so I don't want to draw a conclusion. I just wanted to have some extra pair of eyes on this issue before I report it, because llvm has 17,000 open issues, I didn't want to waste their time (I reported the issue: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/53217)

Comment: I added more information about the shift. There are two issues, the register copying and the right shift. Both happen with unsigned calculations, the register copying only happens on CISC/weakly orthogonal platforms like x86 with the limited mul compared to imul.

Comment: You were right about BuildExactSDIV. Good of you to report.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, and if it turns out that this is indeed the case, I'll accept it. Thanks!